# Edit Model - Is there any better way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a WebGrid on my form with one of the column having ActionLink as:

```
Html.ActionLink((string)item.Name, "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
```

The purpose of below code is to show Edit screen as a Modal popup and post updated object successfully.

Controller - Get:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    ... //Fetch employeeViewModel @id
    TempData["StateData"] = employeeViewModel ;
    TempData["ViewState"] = "Edit";

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@if (TempData.ContainsKey("ViewState") && TempData["ViewState"].ToString() == "Edit")
{
    EmployeeViewModel employeeViewModel = (employeeViewModel)TempData["StateData"];
    @Html.Partial("_EditEmployee", employeeViewModel)

    <script language="javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#editEmployeeModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
}
```

Edit form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editEmployeeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
...
```

All this is working fine with complete cycle of Get/Post model for editing.
However, I am concerned about the extra trip that I am making in Controller-Get method:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Can anyone please guide for a better approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just a general pointer: you don't need to go to the server to pop up a modal dialog in the browser. You can do this just fine in javascript alone. Several of the common javascript libraries already have modal popups that you can use/customise/borrow etc. to suit your needs. Just google "javascript popup form" for lots of information.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but isn't my code using js to load the modal popup - $('#editEmployeeModal').modal('show'); I am just wondering how shall I return from the controller Edit action so I don't have to call - return RedirectToAction("Index");

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose of below code is to show Edit screen as a Modal popup and post updated object successfully.

Before directly answering your question I want to talk about this for a moment. You need to be sure that a modal is the right choice. Is there some state you need to preserve? Does a modal present a better user experience? Does the modal work across platforms and with older technology?

Using modals is almost always more complicated than simply redirecting to another page and then back. Weigh the extra complexity against the user experience. If it isn't justified then abandon it. Also think about the weird situations you can end up with. What happens when your modal needs to open another modal?

Now the real question...How to make it work. In short, use AJAX.

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)item.Name, "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
```

Have this open the modal. The modal contains an AJAX form element (Ajax.BeginForm()) and POST that to your Edit action.

Now there is no redirection. When the action completes execute a javascript function setup through the Ajax form's `AjaxOptions` that closes the modal (or shows validation). The user never leaves the page through the whole process.